# Time Picker Fragments Differentiation

Tags: android, android-fragments, timepicker, android-timepicker

I have run into a problem where my app is properly building and buttons are working as expect, but the text field I am editing with two time picker fragments is being edited by both the start time picker and end time picker.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_picker_button);
        button_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker1 = new TimePickerStartFragment();
                timePicker1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"time picker start");
            }
        });

        Button button_end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_picker_button);
        button_end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker2 = new TimePickerEndFragment();
                timePicker2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"time picker end");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker TimePickerStartFragment, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Hour: " + hourOfDay + " " + "Minute: " + minute);
```

My application looks like two buttons, one for a start time fragment and the other for an end time fragment. I have two seperate time picker fragment java files. However, when I set the end time fragment it still modifies the start time text. I want to have the start time picker only modify the start time text and the end time picker modify the end time text.

To further clarify when the select start time button is pressed TimePickerStratFragment is opened and a time is selected, this modifies a text field called textView. However when the time end button fragment is selected it also modifies the text view. I want the time end button to not modify the text view.

[image]

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "when I set the end time fragment it still modifies the start time text". Please clarify.

Comment: Hello, I have edited to clarify the question.

Comment: Your problem is most likely that the `onTimeSet` method is being called for both dialogues, and not just the start dialog. Therefore both dialogues change the TextView.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much, is there a suggested standard solution?

Comment: In the `onTimeSet` method you have a `TimePicker` parameter. Perhaps you could use java's `instanceof` to check if it is a start or an end `TimePicker`. Then, only if it is a start `TimePicker`, you change the text.

Comment: I think there is something else incorrect. The variables that are set by the timepickerstart fragment are not the same as the timepickerendfragment. So I don't see how the textview is being set by the end fragment as well as the start fragment.

Comment: Then test it. Put a print in the `onTimeSet()` method and see if the TimePickerEndFragment being opened calls it or not.

Comment: Smart suggestion, I confirmed that with the print statement, upvoted for proof of issue. Other comment provided solution. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a String value to check which time picker is opened, because onTimeSet is fired for both fragments use something like this

```
String timeTag;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button_start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_picker_button);
        button_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeTag = "from";
                DialogFragment timePicker1 = new TimePickerStartFragment();
                timePicker1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"time picker start");
            }
        });

        Button button_end = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_picker_button);
        button_end.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeTag = "to";
                DialogFragment timePicker2 = new TimePickerEndFragment();
                timePicker2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"time picker end");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker TimePickerStartFragment, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        if(Objects.equals(timeTag, "from")) {
            TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            textView.setText("Hour: " + hourOfDay + " " + "Minute: " + minute);
        }

        if(Objects.equals(timeTag, "to")) {

        }
}
```

Comment: Solution works, this is what I was trying to do exactly.